# cPanel won't deploy even though .cpanel.yml file is present

Tags: git, deployment, push, cpanel, web-hosting

My repo is managed with cPanel on a webhoster. According to various documentations, you need a .cpanel.yml file in the top directory of your repo, to deploy files into a production directory. It doesn't work though.

Here are the contents of .cpanel.yml (which btw. is in the top directory of the repo):

```
---
deployment:
      tasks:
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/glades/public_html
        - /bin/cp -r * $DEPLOYPATH
```

Whereas "glades" is my username. As far as I know it should deploy all files from the repo into the production directory, which is public_html in this case. But when I have a look at the public_html folder with my file manager, none of the files are to be found.

[The file manager shows public_html folder like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1xDR.png)

There should be both, a README.md and a index.php - file. But the index.php is not being altered (it's an old one) and the README.md doesn't even exist.

Now when I go into the "Pull or Deploy" Tab of cPanels "Git Version Control", there's [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFLAk.png). But I can assure you that there is a valid .cpanel.yml file (because when i delete the local repo and clone it again there's a .cpanel.yml file that is being downloaded in the main directory). Also, the checked-out branch is master and I'm the only one working on it right now, so it should be current.
I don't quite get behind it. Does someone see where I go wrong? Appreciated!

Comment: for me it was uncommitted changes in the server (error_log) file added to the repo by the server so i added  this file to git and push to remote and then everything this is working then.:)

Answer (score 3):

what solved this for me is using more context on the first path, which is where the files will be moved *from*. in your case, try this:

```
---
deployment:
      tasks:
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/glades/public_html
        - /bin/cp -r /home/glades/<repositories>/<repo>/* $DEPLOYPATH
```

of course, replace `<repositories>/<repo>` with the location of your repositories and repo on your webserver.

Comment: After hours of searching, this was what worked. It would be interesting to know why an absolute path is sometimes needed, since I've seen many others use short/relative ones.